# Play Framework custom Unmarshaller with custom media type

Tags: json, scala, playframework, unmarshalling, media-type

I have a custom JSON media type like: `application/vnd.custom+json`. I wrote Readers and Writers or better to say Formatters for my `MyCustomObj`.

I want to write marshaller and unmarshaller for this content type. I was successful with marshaller but not getting unmarshaller to work for Play! JSON support. Code snippet:

```
val `application/vnd.custom+json` = MediaTypes.register(MediaType.custom("application/vnd.custom+json"))

trait PlayMyCustomSupport extends PlayMyCustomFormat with PlayJsonSupport {
  implicit val playMyCustomMarshaller =
    Marshaller.delegate[MyCustomObj, JsValue](`application/vnd.custom+json`)(Json.toJson(_))

  // This ".asOpt.get" is just a hack to test if it works. Will implement later properly.
  implicit val playMyCustomUnmarshaller =
    Unmarshaller.delegate[JsValue, MyCustom](`application/vnd.custom+json`)(Json.fromJson[MyCustomObj](_).asOpt.get)
}
```

My test looks like:

```
"allow unmarshalling a Json to a my custom object" in {
  val myCustomObj = MyCustomObj("foobar")
  val httpEntity = HttpEntity(`application/vnd.custom+json`, """{"custom":"foobar"}""")
  assert(httpEntity.as[MyCustomObj] === Right(myCustomObj))
}
```

When I run the test I get error like:

```
[info] - allow unmarshalling a Json to a my custom object *** FAILED ***
[info]   Left(UnsupportedContentType(Expected 'application/json')) did not equal Right(MyCustomObj(foobar))
```

So somehow my custom Media Type is not registered or something? Strange that above marshaller works fine.

Thanks!

Best